# PHPUnit + Guzzle : Cookie persistence between test methods

Tags: php, cookies, phpunit, session-cookies, guzzle

I am using PHPUnit and Guzzle to make API unit test. The probleme I have is that I am not able or I can't really figure out how to persiste cookie between my test methods. Or maybe am doing it all wrong ^^

The first test `testGetFirst` gets the data and set a session cookie on server side. The response has a `Set-Cookie` header with the right cookie.

The seconde test `testGetSecond`  should return a data set if the cookie exists. Unfortunatelly it seems that `Guzzle::Client` doesn't store/persiste the cookie between the methods.

```php
    use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;
    use GuzzleHttp\Client;

    class MyTest extends Testcase
    {
        public $guzzleClient;

        /**
         * @before
         */
        function initVariables() {
            $this->guzzleClient = new Client([
                'base_uri' => 'http://apiuri.com',
                'cookies'  => true
            ]);
        }


        // This call get some data and set a cookie (session cookie) on server side          
        function testGetFirst() {
            $params = [
                'query' => [
                    'param1' => 'myparam'
                ]                
            ];

            $response = $this->guzzleClient->request('GET', '/', $params);
            // if I print out the response headers I get my cookie in 'Set-Cookie' header
            // I suppose the cookie has been set correctly 
            print_r($response->getHeaders());

            // if I print out the client conf cookie, I get the cookie too
            print_r($this->guzzleClient->getConfig('cookies')->toArray());
        }

        // This call get data to have access it need to use a cookie that has been set by testGetFirst
        // But unfortunatelly the cookie is empty while making the request
        /**
         * @depends testGetFirst
         */
        function testGetSecond() {
            $params = [
                'query' => [
                    'param1' => 'hello'
                ]
            ];

            // if I print out the client conf cookie, cookies is empty
            print_r($this->guzzleClient->getConfig('cookies')->toArray());

            $response = $this->guzzleClient->request('GET', '/second', $params);             
            // as  the request can't access to a cookie it sends an error response
        }


    }
```

I know there is `CookieJar` that I can use in each method and pass the `Set-Cookie` value in to `Jar` but I was hopping to avoid it.

Do you have any idea or suggestion ?

Very appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the `@before` annotation for the `initVariables` method, this method is executed before each test. That method is creating a fresh client before each test.

To solve your particular situation, since you're using the `@depends testGetFirst` annotation, you could have the `testGetFirst` method return the client object. The `testGetSecond` method can then receive it as an argument. Check the [Test Dependencies documentation](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/8.2/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit-test-dependencies) for more info regarding passing arguments into dependent tests.